# In C++, is there a pattern to make sure the new object pointer generated by the class static method will be deleted?

Tags: c++, class, oop, memory, new-operator

Is there a pattern to make sure the new object pointer generated by the class static method will be deleted?

I have a base class here.

```
// abstract class
class Expression{
    // method here ...
};
```

And a derived class here.

```
class Scaler: public Expression{
public:
    float value;

    Scaler(float _value) : value(_value){};

    static Expression* from(float value) {return new Scaler(value);}
    static Expression* zero(float value) {return from(0);}
}
```

the usage

```
Expression* num1 = Scaler::zero();
Expression* num2 = Scaler::from(69.0f);
//....
delete num1;  // <- is there a way to systematically delete those pointers?
delete num2;
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Unless you wrap it in a container that assumes ownership of the allocation, then managing that allocation is a *you* problem.

Comment: How do you spell RAII?

Comment: @StephenNewell  How do you make a pointer to a derived object and store it in a  unique pointer to the base class like he is trying to do?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `return std::unique_ptr<Expression>(new Scaler(value));`

Comment: I also recall a function (probably a fancy template one) called make_unique.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Does `make_unique` work with derived types?  I thought it didn't which is why I used `new`, but I'd love to be wrong on this one.

Comment: @StephenNewell I just tried the make_unique thing - here is a working example: https://onlinegdb.com/EaUZJwAGr   I didn't expect it to work....

Comment: Oh, I was thinking of covariant return types for some reason.  Yeah, use `make_unique`.

Comment: @StephenNewell Derived types' unique_ptrs convert implicitly to their base's unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
class Expression {
  public:
    virtual ~Expression() {} // <- was missing in your example!
};
class Scaler: public Expression{
  public:
    float value;

    Scaler(float _value) : value(_value){};

    static std::unique_ptr<Expression> from(float value) {
      return std::make_unique<Scale>(value);
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Expression> zero() {return from(0);}
};
```

Crucially, an `std::unique_ptr<Scale>` object will implicitly convert to an `std::unique_ptr<Expression>` because `Scale` publicly inherits from `Expression`. See documentation above.

You can use it just like your example:

```
auto const num1 = Scaler::zero();
auto const num2 = Scaler::from(69.0f);
```